# How to align image in this way in HTML email signature

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I want to align this image in this way. I am making an HTML email signature. I know I can do this with margin negative or position relative but I am using the table and their child tags here and I don't want to use margin padding position properties as these properties do not support by many email platforms like outlook.
So, all I need is to align the image in this way by using table tags and their properties.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. An image of your desired outcome isn't sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as individual elements.

You're relying on a background image plus margin or padding to push the image down into place. This isn't just html email you're building that will be received once, you're building html that is effectively being forwarded and code will be stripped depending on the system you import the signature into as well as any email client cleansing the signature when receiving the signature.

Your only option is to have the white/yellow background, photo and text on the pink tab as one image.